# Is there any meaning of having bootstrap=True, when max_sample=1.0 in case of bagging ensemble learning?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-science, ensemble-learning

In bagging ensemble technique if I use `n_estimator=500`, `max_sample=1.0`, and `bootstrap=True`, then is it not equivalent to `n_estimator=500`, and `bootstrap=False`, as in both case only one sample of 500 training instances will be given to our predictor? Assuming number of training instances=500.

Comment: Assuming Number of total instances =500 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not equivalent.

When you specify `bootstrap=False`, you are basically saying that each of your weak estimators should be trained using every data point in your training set exactly once.

When you specify `bootstrap=True`, you are drawing with replacement, meaning that some data points might be used more than once and others not. `max_samples` is just a way to determine out of what data fraction you can bootstrap.